# constructing a minimum spanning tree using java's TreeMap

Tags: java, graph, tree

I'm working on a project that requires me to keep track of a number of points on a 2d plane. I need to add functionality that allows for certain points to detect the proximity of other points. I immediately thought of the closest pair problem and thought that maybe I should construct a minimum spanning tree.

The first issue is, these points constantly update their coordinates and I was wondering if it would even be plausible to do this.

The other issue is, I can't use 3rd party libraries for this so no jgraph or jung. I was wondering if there is a way to construct a minimum spanning using just the libraries I've been given. Can TreeMap be used or would I have to do this from scratch?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  What libraries "have you been given"?  Is this homework?

Comment: any libraries that come with jdk 6. It's a homework project, yes, but i'm not asking for a coded answer. This is just an idea I had to complete a small part of the project and wanted to know if I was on the right track.

Comment: What do you mean "detect the proximity of other points?"  Are you trying to do queries that return points close to another point (e.g. Nearest Neighbor)?

Comment: 'TreeMap` in Java doesn't really have anything to do with `Tree` algorithms per-se, it is an implementation of the `Map` interface that happens to use a `Tree` structure for storage.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to do *Nearest Neighbor* queries.  That is where you try to find a point (or points) closest to another point. For a naive solution, you can just store a list of points and iterate through them using the distance formula to figure out which ones are closest.  But if you want to do queries more quickly, you will want to use a spatial data structure that enables these kinds of queries.  I would suggest a KD Tree.  Java does not come with a KD Tree implementation in its standard library so you'll need to implement that yourself.

A TreeMap is just an implementation of the `Map` interface that lets you put and retrieve values by their keys.  If you want to write something to generate a minimum spanning tree, you'll need to do that yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm looking in to that now.

Answer (score 0):

On very Object Oriented way of doing this would have the `Point` Objects use the `Observer Pattern` and register themselves as Observers of all the other points, then as points positions change they can update all the Observers that they changed. You could control the thresholds of how often the changes occurred or by how much the changed needed to be by before the notifications were sent to the Observers. This would work well since you said, "certain" points need to track proximity and not all.